# WebApi calling Async method hangs on the inner Async call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am calling Async method in a non-async method in the below way in WebApi authentication handler. And it hangs when it executes the inner external Async method. I need to set the claims before the subsequent code executes. So I am setting the return value to the Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Please advise.

I have tried the below and none of them worked.

1. `Task.Run(() => Thread.CurrentPrincipal = this.ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult());` - this works but the subsequent code execution does not wait on this and so the claims are not utilized there.
2. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = this.ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken).Result;`
3. `Task<ClaimsPrincipal> claimsPrincipalTask = this.ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken);
   Task.WaitAll(claimsPrincipalTask);
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

---

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = this.ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

---

```
private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> ValidateTokenAsync(string accessToken)
    {
        LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceInformation("Validating JWT.");

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;            

        if (principal == null || principal.Identity == null || !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            principal = await JwtValidator.ValidateTokenAsync(accessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return principal;
    }
```

---

The JwtValidator.ValidateTokenAsync method:

```
public static async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> ValidateTokenAsync(string accessToken)
    {
        string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

        string issuer = null;
        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", authority);

        List<SecurityToken> signingTokens = null;

        try
        {
            // The issuer and signingTokens are cached for 24 hours. They are updated if any of the conditions in the if condition is true.
            if (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(stsMetadataRetrievalTime).TotalHours > 24
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(globalIssuer)
                || globalSigningTokens == null)
            {
                // Get tenant information that's used to validate incoming jwt tokens
                ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint);
                OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                globalIssuer = config.Issuer;
                globalSigningTokens = config.SigningTokens.ToList();

                stsMetadataRetrievalTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }

            issuer = globalIssuer;
            signingTokens = globalSigningTokens;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceWarning("Failed to get signing tokens.");
            throw;
        }

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = audience,
            ValidIssuer = issuer,
            IssuerSigningTokens = signingTokens,
            CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None
        };

        ClaimsPrincipal principal;

        try
        {
            // Validate token.
            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(
                accessToken,
                validationParameters,
                out validatedToken);
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException)
        {
            LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceWarning("Failed to validate the JWT.");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            LoggingUtilities.Logger.TraceWarning("Failed to validate the JWT.");
            throw;
        }

        return principal;
    }
```

Comment: Using `Task.Run` on ASP-NET will hinder performance because you'll be just switching from a thread pool thread to another thread pool thread and back after the task is completed. All the code and context switching for nothing.

Comment: Calling `Task.Result`, `Task.Wiait` and `Task.WaitAll` can deadlock when in the presence of a synchronization context such as in ASP.NET.